# Wie könnte man "spouse" gender-neutral übersetzen?

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request, noun, political-correctness, gender-neutrality

Das Wort *spouse* ist im Englischen eine genderneutrale Bezeichnung für den/die Ehepartner/-in.

Wie könnte ich es übersetzen, und dabei diese Neutralität bewahren?

*Ehepartner* ist vermutlich am nähsten, ich bin aber nicht zufrieden, besonders, da mit *Ehepartnerin* eine weibliche Form dieses Wortes ja existiert (und damit wieder keine Neutralität).

Alle anderen Wörter, die mir einfielen, waren noch schlimmer: *Ehemann/-frau, Lebensgefährte/-in, Ehegatte/-weib*.
Auch meine liebsten Online-Wörterbücher konnten mir nicht weiterhelfen
([dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/spouse.html), 
[Leo](https://dict.leo.org/?search=spouse),
[Pons](http://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/englisch-deutsch/spouse),
[Open Thesaurus](https://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/Ehepartner),
[Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/spouse)).

Comment: Interessanterweise gibt es die (vermutlich) verwandten Formen [Gespons](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gespons_Braeutigam_Gatte_Ehemann) und (bayerisch) _Gspusi_, die auch weitgehend bis ganz "Gender-neutral" daherkommen. Aber das eine ist veraltet, und das andere meint eher eine unverheiratete Beziehung - für eine Übersetzung von _spouse_ also leider untauglich.

Comment: Ich weiss nicht genau, warum hier so auf den "Ehe"-Partner gezielt wird. Meiner Erfahrung mit meinen englischsprechenden Kollegen nach ist zumindestens im gegenwärtigen englischen Sprachgebrauch "spouse" nicht ans Verheiratetsein gebunden. Auch der irische Kollege, der mit einem Mann zusammenlebt, sagt "Let's go for a drink tonight and bring the spouses"

Comment: Ehegatte (gender neutral); Ehegatting (feminine); Ehegatterich (maskuline, humorous)

Comment: @caconyrn It is Gattin, not Gatting. Surely just a typo, but learners may not know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich habe die bisher unbelegte – d.h. ich habe erfolglos nach entsprechenden Studien gesucht und keine eigene durchgeführt – Theorie, dass *+er*, moviert zu *+erin(nen)* wie in *Partnerin(nen)*, stärker mit männlichen Individuen assoziiert wird als *+e(n)*, moviert zu *+in(nen)* wie in *Gattin(nen)*. Sollte diese Hypothese zutreffen, wäre zumindest unter dem gewünschten Neutralitätsgesichtspunkt das etwas altbackene ***Gatte*** gegenüber *Partner* zu bevorzugen.

Von *Gatten* wird üblicherweise angenommen, dass sie verheiratet sind, daher ist *Ehegatten* meist unnötig, weil redundant. Bei *Partner* müsste der genaue Beziehungsstatus ggf. spezifiziert werden, wobei v.a. die Komposita ***Ehepartner*** und *Lebenspartner* üblich sind.

Daneben gibt es das morphologisch ähnliche *Gefährte / Gefährtin*, aber meistens beschränkt auf die Zusammensetzungen ***Lebensgefährten*** und *Lebensabschnittsgefährten* (LAG), welches nicht mehr nur flapsig gebraucht wird, aber beide legen meistens eine nicht amtlich eingetragene oder kirchlich abgesegnete Beziehung nahe.

Sowohl ***Gespons*** als auch ***Gemahl*** halte ich für zu **veraltet**, um ernsthaft verwendet zu werden. Zu ersterem gibt es tatsächlich keine movierte Form, weswegen es vom Sprachsystem her als geschlechtsneutral gelten dürfte, aber nicht zwingend auch im Sprachgebrauch ist. Schade eigentlich. Man könnte natürlich auch mal linguistisch bewanderte Feminist(inn)en fragen, bspw. [Luise Pusch](http://www.fembio.org/biographie.php/frau/blog).

In Leitfäden und Empfehlungen für einen nicht sexisitischen Sprachgebrauch werden häufig substantivierte Partizipien oder Adjektive als gute Lösung angesehen, da sie zumindest im Plural keinen Rückschluss auf das Geschlecht zulassen. Tatsächlich ist bereits ein solches Wort etabliert, nämlich *der/die **Angetraute**, die Angetrauten* (aber: *ein Angetraute**r***). Allerdings kann gerade diese Formulierung als hierarchisch verstanden werden, d.h. die untergeordnete Frau wird dem übergeordnetem Mann angetraut/anvertraut (oder andersrum) und nicht zwei gleichwertige Menschen förmlich miteinander verbunden. 
*Verlobte* ist zwar auch ein substantiviertes Partizip, bezeichnet aber den vorehelichen Zustand. Man kann zwar von *meiner Verlobten* sprechen, aber nicht von *meiner Verheirateten* oder *meiner Angeheirateten*.

Nur umgangssprachlich und entweder abwertend oder scherzhaft-liebevoll möglich ist außerdem *Alte(r)* oder *Holde(r)* sowie diverse Kosenamen wie *Schatz*.

Andererseits hängt auch viel vom Kontext, dem Medium, der Textsorte und dem Publikum ab, bspw. kann mitunter *Begleitung* oder sogar *Anhang* treffend sein. @Matthias Kommentar, dass man konkret sein sollte, wenn erwartet werden kann, dass man konkret sein könnte, ist richtig und wichtig (und entspricht bestimmt irgendeiner der Grice’schen [Konversationsmaximen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konversationsmaximen)).

Wenn möglich, sollte man zwei Menschen, die eine gleichberechtigte Beziehung miteinander führen, gemeinsam bezeichnen, also als *Paar* bzw. spezieller als ***Ehepaar*** oder mit dem Pluraletantum ***Eheleute***. Wenn man die Namen oder geschlechtsbezogene Bezeichnungen wie *Ehemann* und *Ehefrau* verwendet, stellt sich nämlich häufig noch die Frage, ob man mit der gewählten Reihenfolge (Frauen zuerst im „Titanic-Prinzip“, z.B. *Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren*, vs. *Adam und Eva*) eine Bevorzugung ausdrückt oder vermittelt.

Fazit: **Nein**, es gibt wie im Deutschen bei fast allen personenbezeichnenden Substantiven kein eindeutig geschlechtsneutrales Äquivalent für das englische *spouse*, zumindest kein allgemein verständliches und gebräuchliches.

Comment: "dass man konkret sein sollte, wenn erwartet werden kann, dass man konkret sein könnte" - Du hast mich besser verstanden als ich selbst ;-) Aber auch sonst gebe ich hier gerne +1

Comment: Will denn *Genderismus* nicht genau das Gegenteil von *konkret sein* und damit möglichst alle Möglichkeiten offen lassen?

Comment: Ich habe in Bezug auf *Partner* und *Gatte* ganz das entgegengesetzte Gefühl.

Comment: @ludi Falls meine Hypothese zu den Morphemen im Allgemeinen zutreffen sollte, können Wörter trotzdem im Sprachgebrauch noch stärker konnotiert sein. Mit anderen Worten: ich bin geneigt, dir in diesem speziellen Fall zuzustimmen.

Comment: @Crissov oh, das stimmt natürlich. Ich wollte Ihnen die Hypothese auch nicht madig machen! Viel Glück!

Answer (score 6):

"Partner" für *Spouse* ist an sich gut genug. "Ehepartner" ist mir fast schon ein bißchen zu spezifisch. (Und ich finde überhaupt nix dran, dass bei so einem Begriff der sprachliche Begriff u.U. ein anderes Genus als das "Geschlecht" hat - Wer mal genau hingekuckt hat, hat ziemlich sicher festgestellt, dass das irgendwie was anderes ist...)

Edit: Ich plädiere mit Absicht für das Weglassen der "Ehe", weil das eher ein kulturelles als ein sprachliches Konzept ist, das nicht ohne weiteres durch blosses Übersetzen des Wortes transferiert werden kann. Man stelle sich eine fiktive Unterhaltung zwischen einem Saudischen Prinzen, der mit 4 Frauen verheiratet ist, und einem schwulen Mann, der mit einem Mann verheiratet ist, über ihre Ehepartner (die sie beide als "spouse" bzw. "Partner" bezeichnen würden) vor. Konkret in der Sprache zu sein dürfte hier annähernd unmöglich sein, weil sich die kulturellen Konzepte der beiden so sehr unterscheiden.

Comment: Nach meinem Verständnis der Frage ist _ein_ Wort gesucht, das auf beide Geschlechter anwendbar ist. Eine Frau wäre aber eine _Partnerin_.

Comment: Nein. Eine Frau *kann* eine "Partnerin" sein, aber auch ein "Partner". Hier sind tatsächlich die Männer von der Sprache benachteiligt, die dürfen höchstens "Partner" sein. Eigentlich habe ich **genau deshalb** geschrieben, dass *sprachliches* und *tatsächliches* Geschlecht nicht dasselbe sind.

Comment: "Heute abend kommt der Franz mit seinem Partner" - da werden unmißverständlich zwei Männer erwartet.

Comment: Wenn der Franz mit seinem Partner kommt, bringt er bei mir die Anne mit. Und wenn bei mir der Kaminfeger kommt, ist er auch eine Frau.

Comment: @Matthias ggf. interessant: "Heute abend kommt der Franz mit seiner besseren Hälfte" ist mMn unmissverständlich ein Mann und eine Frau, wobei das ja theoretisch neutraler ist. (sein müsste?)

Comment: @tofro Das geht bei Berufen oder bei Sätzen wie "Zum Sommerfest brachte jeder seinen Partner mit" - aber nicht, wenn es um eine konkrete Person geht, von der der Sprecher weiß oder mit hoher Wahrscheinlichkeit erwarten kann, dass es eine Frau ist. Abgesehen davon: soweit ich weiß, sind _spouses_ immer verheiratet, es müsste für eine Übersetzung dann also schon der *Ehe*partner sein.

Comment: @Vogel612 Meinst Du? Ich hätte kein Problem damit, den Gatten eines Mannes scherzhaft als seine "bessere Hälfte" zu bezeichnen.

Comment: @Matthias Zu deinem Argument des "Verheiratetseins" - Es gibt inzwischen so viele Arten, auf die man "verheiratet sein" kann, dass man sie nicht mehr so einfach allgemein über Sprach- und Kulturgrenzen hinweg durch einfache Übersetzung übertragen kann. Aus diesem Grund habe ich die "Ehe" weggelassen.